# Postgres unix socket directory not persisting

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm provisioning an Ubuntu virtual machine using Vagrant + Ansible. Postgres installs correctly but on each machine restart and reload the directory /var/run/postgresql is missing and the postgresql service fails to start up. To get postgres running, I need to create the unix socket directory and manually start the service.

If I try and start the service without the socket directory I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot stat /var/run/postgresql
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

How can I get around this?

EDIT

Here's my postgresql playbook instructions

```
---
- name: Install Postgres + PostGIS
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=installed update_cache=yes
  with_items:
    - libgeos-dev
    - postgresql-9.3
    - postgresql-contrib-9.3
    - postgresql-client-9.3
    - postgresql-server-dev-9.3
    - postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
    - postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts
  sudo: yes
  notify:
    - restart postgresql

- name: PostgreSQL on statup
  service: name=postgresql enabled=yes state=started
  sudo: yes
  notify:
    - restart postgresql

- name: Install PostgreSQL config file
  sudo: yes
  template: src=postgresql.conf
            dest=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
            owner={{ postgresql.user }}
            group={{ postgresql.group }}
  notify:
    - restart postgresql

- name: Install PostgreSQL Host-Based-Authentication file
  template: src=pg_hba.conf.j2
            dest=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
            owner={{ postgresql.user }} group={{ postgresql.group }}
  notify: restart postgresql
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: how are you installing Postgres? Please include that recipe.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/postgresql` is not supposed to persist across reboots. Typically `/var/run` links inside a temporary filesystem anyway.

The start sequence of postgresql as packaged by Ubuntu is done by this function, in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`:

```
# start all clusters of version $1
# output according to Debian Policy for init scripts
start() {
    # create socket directory
    if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
        chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
    else
        install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
    fi

    do_ctl_all start "$1" "Starting PostgreSQL $1 database server"
}
```

This function creates the directory, so when it's missing, it's presumably because PostgreSQL was not started, as opposed to the other way round, PostgreSQL not starting because the directory is missing.